# ANOVA for median and interquartile range

Tags: anova, bootstrap, median, interquartile

I have 5 samples of different sizes (5000-15000 observations each) from 5 (presumably different) distributions. I need to perform something like ANOVA to test the hypothesis that these distributions have the same median and interquartile range. If I would be interested only in medians I would use the Kruskal-Wallis test, but I need also interquartile range.

**Is there is a way to perform such a test, may with permutations?**

P.S. I assume that samples come from different distributions, but these distributions have the same IQR and median, and differences starts from higher order statistics.

Comment: With such huge samples, you'll almost certainly reject using any reasonable test -- your ability to identify trivially small differences will be substantial.

Comment: Great point, @Glen_b!  That is why it will be important to supplement the test results with confidence intervals for the differences in true medians (or IQR's).

Comment: Indeed, but then why test at all? Doesn't an interval for the difference in medians (or whatever other statistic) convey the necessary information about the size of the difference?

Answer (score 3):

Quantile regression allows you to test any quantile. Here is an example in R

```
> library(quantreg)
> summary(rq(mpg~cyl+disp+hp,c(0.25,0.5,0.75),data=mtcars))

Call: rq(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, tau = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 
    data = mtcars)

tau: [1] 0.25

Coefficients:
            coefficients lower bd upper bd
(Intercept) 26.53473     26.32579 30.86801
cyl         -0.31763     -1.33117 -0.14118
disp        -0.02588     -0.02827 -0.00917
hp          -0.00672     -0.06947  0.00266

Call: rq(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, tau = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 
    data = mtcars)

tau: [1] 0.5

Coefficients:
            coefficients lower bd upper bd
(Intercept) 33.06030     27.49147 38.66943
cyl         -1.52147     -2.57978 -0.41709
disp        -0.01632     -0.03119  0.00197
hp          -0.00292     -0.03085  0.00132

Call: rq(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, tau = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 
    data = mtcars)

tau: [1] 0.75

Coefficients:
            coefficients lower bd upper bd
(Intercept) 41.03835     27.01372 47.45651
cyl         -2.26654     -4.27368  2.81358
disp        -0.01191     -0.04720  0.02987
hp          -0.01290     -0.04689  0.01637
```

And you can also run an ANOVA

```
> anova(rq(mpg~cyl+disp+hp,c(0.25,0.5,0.75),data=mtcars))

Quantile Regression Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp
Joint Test of Equality of Slopes: tau in {  0.25 0.5 0.75  }

  Df Resid Df F value Pr(>F)
1  6       90  1.6521 0.1421
```

Comment: Does `anova.rq()` take into account the covariance structure of estimates from different quantiles?

Comment: @JustGettinStarted I don't think so, I cannot find any information on it.

Comment: @ user2974951 if you check out page 49 of Lingxin Hao's brief on QR (see link). You see that for comparing quantile estimates you need to take into account cross-quantile covariance. `anova.rq()` should do this already?but I'm not positive that it does. https://nguyenvantien0405.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/quantile_regressiolingxin-hao.pdf